# Bundling multiple versions of Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP MVC application using jquery from Nuget.

Recently I upgraded to the latest version on NUGET which is currently 2.0.3. This version doesn't support older browsers (specifically IE8).

There is a trick to get around it [using conditional comments](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/).

My question is what is the best method to make this work with the bundling? Currently

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

I have added two bundles one

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryold").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2*"));
```

Then on the layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryold")
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Or is there a better way? Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: if you need to support ie8 why not just use 1.* - 2.* is just a stripped down version that removes the support for older browsers so there is no point you using it if you need to support the older browsers

Comment: @Pete, two reasons I want to follow what is released on Nuget, and given that the majority of clients will be using modern browsers. Therefore for the majority it makes more sense to include the stripped down version.

Comment: Just seems like an extra bit of downloading - the point of having bundles is to minimise the amount of files the end user has to download

Comment: @Pete think, you might be misunderstanding, they client will only receive one of the bundles conditionally on what version of IE they use. So the majority will only ever see 2+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you partly answered your question
So you can have

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery_OLD").Include( "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.*.js")); 
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include( "~/Scripts/jquery-2.*.js"));
```

You just need to add two different bundle names one can be jquery old, second just jquery.

Comment: Makes sense, I've updated my question to build in your answer. I had to make a small modification to the syntax

Comment: ok will there be jquery compatibility issue ? when using jquery 1.11.0 and 1.7.0.